# Iterating with a jquery.().each and for loop fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I am trying to get data from two objects and to avoid the (this) keyword to collide I thought using an each and for loop with the two objects would work. But I cant make them cooperate properly. The frustrating thing is I get now errors in the console. My Code:

```
var times = {
  startTimes: [{
    start: '10:00'
  }, {
    start: '11:00'
  }, {
    start: '12:00'
  }],
  endTimes: [{
    end: '10:00'
  }, {
    end: '11:00'
  }, {
    end: '12:00'
  }]
}
var items = [];
jQuery(obj).each(function() {
  if (this.ID === parseInt(inputID)) {

    for (var i in times) {
      var item = {
        id: this.ID,
        start: times.startTimes[i].start,
        end: times.endTimes[i].end
      }
      items.push(item);
    }

  }
});
```

What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use [`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate object i.e. `jQuery.each(obj, function (index, elem) {`. note `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, __exclusively__, over a jQuery object.

Comment: Should be `jQuery.each(obj, function() {})`

Comment: What is `obj` referring to? What are the errors you're getting?

Comment: I wasnt getting any errors until right now, changed code to Mark.C suggestion: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined`

Comment: The first argument of the .each() function needs to be either an array or an object you want to iterate trough. Like Rory asked what is the `obj` variable?

Answer (score 1):

`.each()` is a function of jQuery object, from official docs found here: [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

> Description: Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for
>   each matched element.

And:

> When called it iterates over the DOM elements that are part of the
>   jQuery object.

And you are calling it on something that is surely not made of DOM objects.

You could use what has been suggested in the comments or opt for vanilla here:

```
    arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
       //your iterator
    }[, thisArg]);
```

See the documentation: [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Also, logic inside seems weird to me, what are you trying to achieve here?